Buscar y mostrar palabra repetida en cadena de texto en Sql Server
buenas tardes, tengo un tema que es el siguiente si es posible que me puedan ayudar:
Tengo un texto ejemplo: ‘(a): Incompatibilidad 1 (b): Correcto (c): Incompatibilidad 2’
En estos momentos necesito extraer la palabra Incompatibilidad, lo cual logro hacerlo sin problema con la ayuda de la función SUBSTRING y CHARINDEX, el detalle es que solo me trae un resultado (el primero) y no ambos, ¿Habrá alguna forma de extraer ambas palabras del texto?
Ejemplo Resultado a obtener: Incompatibilidad 1 - Incompatibilidad 2
Muchas Gracias

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! podrias sumar otro substring.. podrias usar un replace para sacar lo del medio.. sin mucha mas informacion, dificil ayudarte.. igual, si tenes que escribir un query que haga eso... algo esta mal de entrada...

Hola Cristian, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma. Con respecto a tu pregunta, presiona [edit] y agrega la consulta que has realizado (no importa que no funcione) y también el motor de tu base de datos (SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres, etc.)

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Te dejo una solución que sirve para versiones actuales de SQL Server. Utiliza la función STRING_SPLIT para separar la cadena en los distintos valores. También utiliza CROSS APPLY para poder hacer referencia a valores de tablas anteriores y evitar repetir expresiones.Otra función que se utiliza es STRING_AGG para generar una nueva cadena.
DECLARE @Cadena varchar(8000) = '(a): Incompatibilidad 1 (b): Correcto (c): Incompatibilidad 2';

-- Usamos la función STRING_AGG para unir los múltiples valores repetidos.
-- Indicamos el orden en el que se unirán usando la clausula WITHIN GROUP
SELECT STRING_AGG( limpio.valor, ' - ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY split.ordinal ASC)
-- Separamos la cadena cada vez que se abra un paréntesis
FROM   STRING_SPLIT( @Cadena, '(', 1) split
-- Eliminamos todo lo que está antes de cada valor
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT SUBSTRING( split.value, 5, 8000) AS valor) limpio
-- Eliminamos filas vacias
WHERE limpio.valor <> ''
-- Agrupamos por la primer palabra de cada valor (eliminamos el número)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING( limpio.valor, 0, CHARINDEX( ' ', limpio.valor))
-- Indicamos que solo traiga repetidos
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

Si quisieras utilizarlo contra una tabla en vez de una variable, solo hay que usar APPLY una vez más.
-- Creando datos de prueba
CREATE TABLE #Ejemplo( cadena varchar(8000))
INSERT INTO #Ejemplo
VALUES('(a): Incompatibilidad 1 (b): Correcto (c): Incompatibilidad 2');

--Aquí inicia la solución.
SELECT STRING_AGG( limpio.valor, ' - ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY split.ordinal ASC)
FROM   #Ejemplo e
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT( e.cadena, '(', 1) split
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT SUBSTRING( split.value, 5, 8000) AS valor) limpio
WHERE limpio.valor <> ''
GROUP BY SUBSTRING( limpio.valor, 0, CHARINDEX( ' ', limpio.valor))
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;


Puedes valerte de un CTE recursivo para ir obteniendo cada una de las apariciones de la tabla.
Lo primero que me viene a la mente sería algo como:

Filtrar todos los registros donde no aparezca el texto a buscar
En dónde aparece, detectar el inicio y fin de cada aparición. Esto se puede lograr con la función charindex(). Para detectar el inicio, buscamos el texto como tal y, de acuerdo a tu ejemplo, para detectar el final, buscamos la siguiente aparición de un paréntesis de apertura (.
Para los casos dónde la expresión es la última, charindex del paréntesis nos va a devolver cero (0). En esos casos, tomamos la cadena completa.
Conociendo el inicio y el fin, podemos calcular la longitud de la expresión donde aparece la palabra.
Conociendo el fin, podemos obtener el resto de la cadena, es decir, en otras palabras, eliminar la primera aparición.
Sobre esta nueva cadena, podemos repetir los mismos pasos anteriores. De allí que la solución sea recursiva.

Para realizar estos cálculos de una manera legible y más entendible, hago uso del operador cross apply que, en resumen, nos permite hacer un select sobre cada registro que se va a agregar al resultado de la consulta e integrar el resultado de esa operación a la misma consulta.
Como siempre, el código habla más que mil palabras:
with 
Recursivo as (
select   a.id
       , SUBSTRING(a.texto, b.Inicio, e.Longitud) Incompatibilidad
       , SUBSTRING(a.Texto, d.Fin + 1, LEN(a.texto) - d.Fin) TextoRestante
       , 1 IndiceAparicion
  from MiTabla a
       cross apply (select CHARINDEX('Incompatibilidad', a.texto) Inicio) b
       cross apply (select CHARINDEX('(', a.texto, b.Inicio) IniSiguiente) c
       cross apply (select iif(c.IniSiguiente = 0, len(a.Texto), c.IniSiguiente - 1) Fin) d
       cross apply (select d.Fin - b.Inicio + 1 Longitud) e
 where CHARINDEX('Incompatibilidad', a.texto) != 0
union all
select a.id
       , SUBSTRING(a.TextoRestante, b.Inicio, e.Longitud) Incompatibilidad
       , SUBSTRING(a.TextoRestante, d.Fin + 1, LEN(a.TextoRestante) - d.Fin) TextoRestante
       , a.IndiceAparicion + 1 IndiceAparicion
  from Recursivo a
       cross apply (select CHARINDEX('Incompatibilidad', a.TextoRestante) Inicio) b
       cross apply (select CHARINDEX('(', a.TextoRestante, b.Inicio) IniSiguiente) c
       cross apply (select iif(c.IniSiguiente = 0, len(a.TextoRestante), c.IniSiguiente - 1) Fin) d
       cross apply (select d.Fin - b.Inicio + 1 Longitud) e
 where CHARINDEX('Incompatibilidad', a.TextoRestante) != 0
)
select id, IndiceAparicion, Incompatibilidad
  from Recursivo
 order by id, IndiceAparicion

Con el siguiente conjunto de datos de entrada



id
texto




1
(a): Incompatibilidad 1 (b): Correcto (c): Incompatibilidad 2


2
(a): No


3
(a): Tampoco


4
(a): Incompatibilidad 3 (b): Incompatibilidad 4 (c): Otra cosa


5
(a): No


6
(a): Incompatibilidad 5



El resultado obtenido de ejecutar esta consulta es:
id          IndiceAparicion Incompatibilidad
----------- --------------- --------------------------------------------------------------
1           1               Incompatibilidad 1 
1           2               Incompatibilidad 2
4           1               Incompatibilidad 3 
4           2               Incompatibilidad 4 
6           1               Incompatibilidad 5

fiddle
Con esta información, armar el resultado que buscas es tema de concatenar estos resultados y agrupar por ID:
select id, string_agg(Incompatibilidad, '- ')
  from Recursivo
 group by id;

fiddle
Dado que SQL Server no tiene soporte para string_agg() en versiones anteriores al 2017, puedes usar el truco de armar una salida para XML.
A la consulta anterior, le agregas un par de nuevos CTE's, por ejemplo:
IdsRecursivo as (
select distinct id from Recursivo
)
select   r1.id
       , stuff((
           select '- ' + Incompatibilidad
             from Recursivo r2
            where r2.id = r1.id
              for xml path(''), Type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
       )
  from IdsRecursivo r1
 order by r1.id

Esto ya devuelve como resultado:
id          
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            Incompatibilidad 1 - Incompatibilidad 2
4            Incompatibilidad 3 - Incompatibilidad 4 
6            Incompatibilidad 5

(3 rows affected)

fiddle
Una última consideración, por tema de desempeño, es que podrías obtener los ID's no del resultado recursivo si no de la tabla original, pero qué te conviene más es algo a evaluar solo si tu conjunto de datos es grande y amerita hacer la prueba. Si no es grande, usa cualquiera de las dos.
